# How to make api calls when component is loaded multiple times

Tags: react-native, fetch-api, redux-thunk

I need to fetch products each time a user navigates the products screen of a react native app being built with expo. I found out that the component lifecycle hook : componentDidMount is called just once. This is an issue because if the products are updated on the backend / API, if the componentDidMount is not called again when the user visits the product page again, they won't see latest products which defeats the purpose of the app. How may i approach this ? 
Thanks

Comment: From my opinion fetching data on each rendering will cause the app to go slow, It will be better to add a refreshControl within that product page, So that the user can scroll to refresh by fetching data

Comment: How about a use case where i need to fetch a single product which prices are set from a backend daily. The app is a gas selling app and the prices of the cylinder size changes and i want updated product displayed each time uses navigate to the order page. what do you think is a good approach ? thanks

Comment: For a single product page, I think you can go ahead with your approach of rendering on each load. My above comment is regarding product listing page

Comment: okay, can you share an aproach to always display the latest product detail ? using componentDidMount to fetch the product details seems to work just once. My thinking is that since the component has mounted , it makes no sense for react to fire that method again. what do you think ?

Comment: add a callback function in navigation

Answer (score 3):

1. Use `componentDidUpdate()` method. This will execute automatically before `render()` method gets triggered.

Please read [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillupdate) to know about the life cycle of react-native.

2. Call a function inside `componentDidUpdate()` like this

   componentDidMount() 
     {
       this.loadInitialState();
     }

and then do your API call and set state in `loadInitialState()` function. Hope this will work

Hope it helps .feel free for doubts.

Comment: I have tried that method, that method sits between the component constructor and render, and is called just once not everytime. i need a method that is called everytime like the   render  method

Comment: i see it called once you open the page, if i navigate to the page again, it's not getting called.

Comment: Thanks, it worked but i can't call setState or dispatch an action here. my use case is to be able to call fetch and update state each time a user navigate to that order product page so that user sees the latest product data as set on the backend or API.

Comment: so you can also set state in this method it will update your state every time this function will render.

Comment: Please do green tick if it helps you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add a navigation listener: [Subscribe to updates to navigation lifecycle](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#addlistener-subscribe-to-updates-to-navigation-lifecycle)

```js
this.props.navigation.addListener(
  'didFocus',
  () => {
    this.getData()
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

use WebSocket for realtime application